# track total rotation (twists) of camera in three.js using OrbitControl

Tags: 3d, geometry, three.js, webgl

Currently I'm trying to track the total amount of y rotation users make to a scene in three.js.   I am using OrbitControl and I've fixed the rotation to the y axis.   If I rotated the scene clockwise  3 full rotations and counterclockwise 1 full rotation, I would want to know total rotation is 720 degrees clockwise.

My potential solution involves tracking the camera.rotation.y value changes in the update() function.  However, the value of camera.rotation.y doesn't simply go from 0-2pi in a rotation, it goes from 0 to pi/4 to 0 to -pi/4 to 0 again when I go round in a circle, meaning there are 2 different rotation positions for the same value.  This sounds like a quaternion-like behavour but camera.position seems to be a Euler.

Any tips on a potential solution to this problem ?  I would be so grateful for any insights.

Comment: Yes, three.js uses quaternions. The Euler equivalent is provided for the user's convenience, and the quaternion-to-euler mapping is not unique. You will have to put on your thinking cap for this one. :-)

Comment: OrbitControls is calling rotateLeft/rotateRight. You could track the amount/angle that is input into this methods and somehow convert it to total rotations?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I can override rotateLeft and rotateRight functions and wrap them in something that spits out the change.  Or I will have to use the xz coordinates to calculate the angle but sounds like too much processing overhead.  Thanks folks !